# How to define a table column to always be a math equation, while others are text?

Tags: tables, math-mode

I'd like to typeset a table listing some equations, something like

```
Euler's formula  &    e^{i\phi} &= \cos\phi + i\sin\phi
Euler's identity & 1 + e^{i\pi} &= 0
```

Putting this in a `\begin{tabular}{l|rl}` environment, all formulas would need to be surrounded by `$`'s, while by using `array` the text has to be put into a `\text{...}`. Is there any way to define that one contain by default is text while another is in mathmode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l >{$}r<{$} @{\kern1.4pt} >{$}l<{$} @{}}
Euler's formula  &    e^{i\phi} &= \cos\phi + i\sin\phi \\
Euler's identity & 1 + e^{i\pi} &= 0\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The default tabular header is the definition for

```
-----------col 1---------- ------------col 2 ---------- ---------- col 3---------
\tabcolsep TEXT \tabcolsep \tabcolsep $MATH$ \tabcolsep \tabcolsep $MATH$ \tabcolsep
```

With `@{...}` I can replace the default length `\tabcolsep` where `@{}` ignores this additional horizontal space. Is it *between* two columns then it replaces *both* `\tabcolsep`

Comment: That was quick, thanks! What's the `@` doing? Spacing for the `=`? **edit** Ah yes, [it does](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#.40-expressions)

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: You can avoid the `\kern` command (and guessing the correct value) by `>{$}r<{$}@{}>{${}}l<{$}`; this adds an empty subformula before the `=` symbol, providing the right spacing on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Fur future reference, the [`tabu` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) makes this rather easy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\section{Another possibility}

\begin{tabu} to 0.75\textwidth{X[l] X[r, $] X[l, $]}
Euler's formula  &    e^{i\phi} &= \cos\phi + i\sin\phi \\
Euler's identity & 1 + e^{i\pi} &= 0
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

So just by adding a $ in the definition of the column, its entire content is processed in math mode.
This is what it looks like on screen:
[image: What it looks like on screen]