# Math mode in tabular without having to use $...$ everywhere

Tags: tables, math-mode

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Column A & Column B \\

\begin{math}
x & y \\
\end{math}

\end{tabular}
```

This won't let me compile and gives a lot of errors, how do I enable math mode in a table without using $ on everything?

Comment: If most terms in the table are going to be in math-mode, you could use an `array` environment (while in math-mode, obviously) instead of the `tabular` environment. If it's just the occasional column that's supposed to be in math mode, you could change its column type specifier from, say, `c` to `>{$}c<{$}`.

Comment: To add to Mico's comment: ... and use `\text{Column A}` to switch to text mode in the column headings.

Comment: @longtom `$ ... $` is a short form for `\begin{math} ... \end{math}`, so using the latter is unnecessary verbose.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106692/how-to-define-a-table-column-to-always-be-a-math-equation-while-others-are-text

Comment: @Mico using your example in a tabular column specifier I get "Illegal character in array arg"?  Also even when I try arrays, even when I just copy and paste example code I get "Missing $ inserted \begin{array}{c|c}"

Comment: You must load the `array` package to be able to use the advanced column specification thingy (e.g. `>{$}c<{$}`).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amstext} % for \text macro
\usepackage{array}   % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % math-mode version of "l" column type


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| L | L |}
\hline
\text{Column A} & \text{Column B} \\
x & y \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what do the less than and greater than symbols actually do?

Comment: They simply act as some kind of escape character there. They tell `tabular` that a special column specification follows.

Comment: @STRAIGHTOUTTACOMPTON The [Wikibooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) is basically indispensible for keeping track of how to use tables, at least for me.

Comment: You don't have to use `\text`, you can use `\multicolumn`, too.

Answer (score 41):

If most of the table consists of math-mode material, it's preferable to use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. Any text-mode material in the table can be handled by encasing it in `\text` directives (requires the `amsmath` or the `amstext` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Column A} & \text{Column B} \\
x+y & x-y \\
\hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if my table is all math, but I want to be able to caption and label it?

Comment: @sarahjamal - Do note the use of `\text` directives to typeset the column headers. As you can probably guess, the argument of `\text` is typeset in text mode, not math mode. The material in the argument of `\caption` is typeset in text mode by default.

Answer (score 28):

If you use `tabu`, it automatically detects whether the table is in math mode, thus imitating this feature of `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabu}
\begin{document}
$\begin{tabu}{|l|l|}\hline
  \text{Column A} & \text{Column B} \\
  x & y
\end{tabu}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One really nice feature of this approach (beyond not having to type the complicated array syntax above) is that it preserves syntax highlighting in my editor.

Comment: This approach was very helpful to me, thanks.

Comment: Note that tabu is not maintained anymore and likely to break at any point, cf. https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu