# How can I automatically use typewriter font for one column of a tabular?

Tags: tables, formatting, columns, typewriter

I'm trying to create a table where everything in one column is in typewriter font. In other words, it should perform like this:

```
\begin{tabular} {| l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Sample Table} \\ \hline
\texttt{left a} & right a \\ \hline
\texttt{left b} & right b \\ \hline
\texttt{left c} & right c \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, I'd like to avoid having to type `\texttt` on every line. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112576/math-mode-in-tabular-without-having-to-use-everywhere

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package and its advanced column specifications. The syntax is

```
>{before-code} column-type <{after-code}
```

where `before-code` and `after-code` get executed at the beginning and end (respectively) of each cell of the column in question. Here, you should use

```
>{\ttfamily}l
```

which results in a left-aligned column whose whose cells are typeset in typewriter font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} {| >{\ttfamily}l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Sample Table} \\ \hline
left a & right a \\ \hline
left b & right b \\ \hline
left c & right c \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```