# Math mode in Tabular environment

Tags: math-mode, tabularx, math-operators

With `tabular` or `tabularx` environment, when dealing with numbers , percentages and other math symbols per se, do we need to use the math mode ( `$$` for instance ) with every number/symbol.

Is there an option to enable math mode by default in `tabular` or `tabularx` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [math-mode-in-tabular-without-having-to-use-everywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112576/math-mode-in-tabular-without-having-to-use-everywhere)

Comment: `array` environment?