# How can I define a new environment with multiple optional arguments, and know which one I am using?

Tags: environments, latex3

I want to define an environment that uses two optional arguments, but i want to be able to use one with `<>` and the other with `[]`

Here is what I have done:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\why{O{\equiv}m}%
    { #1 & \quad\langle\;\text{{#2}}\;\rangle }

\NewDocumentCommand\res{m}%
    { & #1}

\NewDocumentCommand\To{}{\Rightarrow}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{derivation}{D<>{1.2} O{0pt}}{
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{#2}
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
}{
  \end{tabular}
  \endgroup
}
```

When I try to use any of the optional arguments either they print in the pdf or I just get an error. How can I fix this?

The code of the example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\why{O{\equiv}m}%
    { #1 & \quad\langle\;\text{{#2}}\;\rangle }

\NewDocumentCommand\res{m}%
    { & #1}

\NewDocumentCommand\To{}{\Rightarrow}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{derivation}{D<>{1.2} O{0pt}}{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{#2}
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
}{
  \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{derivation}<1.5>
          \res{ (p \To \neg q) \land (\neg q \To \neg p) }\\
      \why[\To]{ Transitividad($\To$) }\\
          \res{ p \To \neg p }\\
      \why{ Def.(alt)($\To$) }\\
          \res{ \neg p \lor \neg p }\\
      \why{ Idempotencia($\lor$) }\\
          \res{ \neg p }
  \end{derivation}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently, the issue is the `babel` package.

Comment: I don't know enough to help you immediately, but: (1) `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` already comes with an environment, I don't think you need it.  More importantly, (2) if the arguments are optional, what should happen if they're not given?  Can you show us how you're trying to use  them, so that they print in the pdf or give you an error?

Comment: Ignore (2), I was forgetting that syntax.  (3) I can't get `\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}` to work, even without a new environment.  What are you trying to accomplish with that part?

Comment: The environment work almost the same as `align`. The columns in the `tabular` environment avoid writing `$` in every line of the table.

Comment: @DavidGómez That's just an `array` though ...

Comment: // When I use the method in [tables - Math mode in tabular without having to use $...$ everywhere - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112576/math-mode-in-tabular-without-having-to-use-everywhere) it works well for me, although I got other errors e.g. `\res` is not defined. // so please write a minimal working example (See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means) if you still need help.

Comment: If I take a guess at how to define `\res`, `\why`, and `\To`, I can get your two snippets to compile without any errors.  So I'll echo the request to please extend this into a minimal working example.

Comment: A minimal working example starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, so that we can copy/paste and see the output that you see.  I get your two snippets to compile without any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `babel-spanish` activates `<` and `>` for quotes.

This activation is done at begin document, but your code requires LaTeX to look for “ordinary” `<` and `>`, which it cannot find.

Solution: pass the `es-noquoting` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix} % loads the package 'array', used in the code

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\why{O{\equiv}m}
    { #1 & \quad\langle\;\text{{#2}}\;\rangle }

\NewDocumentCommand\res{m}
    { & #1}

\NewDocumentCommand\To{}{\Rightarrow}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{derivation}{D<>{1.2} O{0pt}}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{#2}%
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}%
}{
  \end{tabular}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{derivation}<1.5>
          \res{ (p \To \neg q) \land (\neg q \To \neg p) }\\
      \why[\To]{ Transitividad($\To$) }\\
          \res{ p \To \neg p }\\
      \why{ Def.(alt)($\To$) }\\
          \res{ \neg p \lor \neg p }\\
      \why{ Idempotencia($\lor$) }\\
          \res{ \neg p }
  \end{derivation}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I removed the call to `xparse` that's not needed since October 2020. Instead I added `fontenc` with the `T1` option, which *is* needed for Spanish.

Check the positions of `%`.

[image]